# How to customize the login page provided by the ABP framework with the angular?

Tags: angular, authentication, abp

How to customize the login page provided by the ABP framework 5.2.2 with the angular template?

we can't found the login component in the abp/ angular project.

Answer (score 0):

Its not actually answer but more a direction you can go. Because i had same issue. Im a backend dev so im little short of front dev knowledge.

So you can add basic theme to your project like in [documentation](https://docs.abp.io/en/abp/latest/UI/Angular/Theming) and in that project you can change login.comp
You can remove navbar or change background and so on like i did but you cant change inputs. At least i was stuck there.

For Abp team. I choose abp for backend because its asp boilerplate not angular. But it would be great to have a documentation for backend devs like my self about customization of ng apps.
For instance how to add primeng comps to basic theme project. It doesnt inherit from main app